# Population means difference using t-distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-distribution

I wanted to understand the solution to a question I got incorrect.

In particular given two independently sampled iid data of different sizes (m and n), possibly different means ($\mu_1, \mu_2$), and same variances, we want to construct a hypothesis test regarding if the population means are the same.

From other SE posts, it seems that this is precisely Gosset's two sample t-test.

The solution uses the t-statistic

$$\frac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-(\mu_1 - \mu_2)}{\sigma \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m}}} \times\frac{n+m-2}{\sqrt{\frac{S_x}{\sigma^2} +\frac{S_Y}{\sigma^2}}}.$$

I am having trouble understanding why this might be the correct solution.

Edit: In particular, I am having trouble understanding why the test statistic might have $\bar{X}-\bar{Y}-(\mu_1 - \mu_2)$ in the numerator.

Comment: What do you mean by correct solution? What (why) is the suspicion here?

Comment: @User1865345 edited post. I am not sure why the numerator makes sense- it measures a deviation of the sample mean differences from the population mean differences. I would've expected it to be the deviation from the sample mean differences to zero.

Comment: So why $\bar X - \bar Y-(\mu_1 - \mu_2)$ in the numerator instead of $\bar X - \bar Y-0 = \bar X -\bar Y?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are considering two normal populations with common variance $\sigma^2$ and means $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y.$ Your null hypothesis is $\mathcal H_0:\mu_X-\mu_Y=\Delta.$

If you note, the statistic $T$ is expressed as $$ T:=\frac{Z}{\sqrt{\frac {S}{m+n-2}}}$$

where $Z:=\frac{(\bar x-\bar y) -\mathbb E(\bar x-\bar y) }{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(\bar x -\bar y) }}\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ and $S=\frac{ms_X^2}{\sigma^2}+\frac{ns_Y^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi^2_{m+n-2}$ the latter being due to additive property of chi square distribution.

So, $T\sim~\mathrm t_{m+n-2}.$

If $\Delta =0, $ then the familiar $t$ statistic follows.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb E\left(\bar x - \bar y\right)$ refers to the expected value *under the null hypothesis*: that is, the null hypothesis you hope to disprove. A very common null hypothesis is that this expected value is zero, but the formula allows for more general tests, should one want to test a null hypothesis that the difference between the means equals one (or whatever).

Comment: Yes @Dave, that is what I intended to say.